# How to let the Navigation Bar (and maybe other stuff) end on the right

Tags: html, css, nav, navigationbar

So I've got a problem with a navigation bar. I've set its width to 100%. But I would like to see the end, because it's got rounded corners...

So like this: | (=======) |

Not like it's now: | (==========|

```css
    #nav {

      height: 60px;

      font-size: 30px;

      line-height: 60px;

      vertical-align: middle;

      text-align: center;

      background-color: #0080FF;

      width: 100%;

      border: 10px solid #16044E;

      border-radius: 20px;

      z-index: 1;

    }

    #nav ul {} #nav li {

      display: inline;

      text-align: center;

      margin: 20px;

    }

    #nav a {

      color: white;

      text-decoration: none;

    }
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Courses</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Subjects</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Log In</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The surrounding container needs a width too.

Comment: @HydraCles Use `@` followed by the person's name to send them a notification about your message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `calc` to reduce `10px` from the total width (`10px` = `border-width`) But you should try `box-sizing:border-box` as the browser support for `calc` is limited [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

```css
#nav {
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    width: calc(100%-10px);
    border: 10px solid #16044E;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul {
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

#nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Subjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Log In</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved :) - I can't give you 'This solved my problem' yet. But I'll give it as soon as possible :3.

Comment: @Akshay: You should add a note about current support of `calc()`: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `#nav`

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

That will make your `width: 100%;` apply to the border part as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `calc()` CSS function with a callback in case you need to support older browsers, here is the [current support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc), and you have to add this to your `#nav`:

```
#nav{
    width: 98%;
    calc(100%-10px);
}
```

Another approach is changing the `box-sizing` of the `#nav` element, so the border will be part of the element width, you may have do update few rules in the CSS but it will work in IE8+, all mobile, and all modern browsers, here the [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing):

```
#nav{
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `#nav` as follows:

**Change** `width: 100%;` *to* `width: auto;`

Your `#nav` should look like this:

```
#nav {
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    width: auto;
    border: 10px solid #16044E;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```